# Launch Jenkins parametrized build from script

Tags: python, jenkins, python-requests

I am trying to launch a Jenkins parametrized job from a python script. Due to environment requirements, I can't install python-jenkins. I am using raw requests module.

This job I am trying to launch has three parameters:

- string (let's call it payload)
- string (let's call it target)
- file (a file, optional)

I've searched and search, without any success.

I managed to launch the job with two string parameters by launching:

```
import requests
url = "http://myjenkins/job/MyJobName/buildWithParameters"
target = "http://10.44.542.62:20000"
payload = "{payload: content}"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
msg = {
    'token': 'token',
    'payload': [ payload ],
    'target': [ target ],
}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=msg)
```

However I am unable to send a file and those arguments in single request.

I've tried `requests.post` file argument and failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it is impossible to send both data and file in a single request via HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

import jenkinsapi
from jenkinsHandler import JenkinsHandler
in your python script

Pass parameters to buildJob() , (like < your JenkinsHandler object name>.buildJob())
JenkinsHandler module has functions like init() , buildJob(), isRunning() which helps in triggering the build

Comment: Yeah, expect I can't use jenkins libraries/packages, preferably `requests` or `urllib`, available with standard Python installation on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
curl -vvv -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/job/jobname/build 
     --form file0='@/tmp/yourfile' 
     --form json='{"parameter": [{"name":"file", "file":"file0"}]}' 
     --form json='{"parameter": [{"name":"payload", "value":"123"}]
     --form json='{"parameter": [{"name":"target", "value":"456"}]}'
```

Comment: OK, so now how can I send it with requests in Python 2?